# Capturing 200 day spend window start dates in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have a table with one column, spend_date_id. For simplicity, this column is denoted as number of days since start of the first spend, so that we have an integer column.

Sample data:

```
spend_date_id
0
350
450
500
550
650
700 and so on
```

I need to associate these dates with an active window, where each active window is of length 200 days from the earliest spend date. Each time an active window ends, a new one starts on the next available spend date.

So, in our example, this would look like

```
spend_date_id    active_window 
0                0
350              1
450              1
500              1
550              2
650              2
700              2 and so on
```

**Window 0**: starts at 0 goes till 199. All dates in this window will have this window number, i.e. date_ids 0.

**Window 1**: starts at 350, goes it 549. All dates in this window will have this window number, i.e. date_ids 350, 450, 500.

Do note that the SQL version available to me, BigQuery, doesn't allow for recursive CTEs.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a single BigQuery query.  Well, if I discount using a user-defined function that processes the data sequentially.

Comment: Does your version of BigQuery support inequality in joins?

Comment: Feel free to use CTEs, UDFs, subquerys, multiple queries and inequalities in joins

Comment: So you want to count how many records happened during the previous 200 days right? Why does record 350 has a count of 1 (should be 0)? Please give more details on your computation rules.

Comment: This is more of a window number. So the window 0 has date 0 in it, window 1 has dates 350, 450, 500 in it.
Window 0: starts at 0 goes till 199. All dates in this window will have this window number
Window 1: starts at 350, goes it 549 and so on. All dates in this window will have this window number

Comment: Just divide the spend_date_id by 200. The result is the active_window value.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for when dateid is 500 in example above.  It will give me 2 but i need 1 as 500 is less than 200 days away from 350.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION splits(arr ARRAY<INT64>, size INT64)
RETURNS ARRAY<INT64>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var cut = parseInt(arr[0]) + parseInt(size);
  var result = [arr[0]];
  for(i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] >= cut) {
      result.push(arr[i]); 
      cut = parseInt(arr[i]) + parseInt(size);  
    }
  };
  return result;
""";
WITH dirty_split AS (
  SELECT spend_date_id, COUNTIF(flag) OVER(ORDER BY spend_date_id) new_big_window
  FROM (
    SELECT spend_date_id, spend_date_id - LAG(spend_date_id) OVER(ORDER BY spend_date_id) > 200 flag
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
), precise_split AS (
  SELECT new_big_window, splits(ARRAY_AGG(spend_date_id), 200) splits
  FROM dirty_split
  GROUP BY new_big_window
), numbering AS (
  SELECT new_big_window, val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY new_big_window, val) - 1 AS active_window
  FROM precise_split, UNNEST(splits) val
)
SELECT spend_date_id, active_window
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
JOIN numbering n
ON t.spend_date_id BETWEEN n.val AND n.val + 200 - 1
-- ORDER BY spend_date_id
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION splits(arr ARRAY<INT64>, size INT64)
RETURNS ARRAY<INT64>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var cut = parseInt(arr[0]) + parseInt(size);
  var result = [arr[0]];
  for(i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] >= cut) {
      result.push(arr[i]); 
      cut = parseInt(arr[i]) + parseInt(size);  
    }
  };
  return result;
""";
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([0,350,450,500,550,650,700]) AS spend_date_id
), dirty_split AS (
  SELECT spend_date_id, COUNTIF(flag) OVER(ORDER BY spend_date_id) new_big_window
  FROM (
    SELECT spend_date_id, spend_date_id - LAG(spend_date_id) OVER(ORDER BY spend_date_id) > 200 flag
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
), precise_split AS (
  SELECT new_big_window, splits(ARRAY_AGG(spend_date_id), 200) splits
  FROM dirty_split
  GROUP BY new_big_window
), numbering AS (
  SELECT new_big_window, val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY new_big_window, val) - 1 AS active_window
  FROM precise_split, UNNEST(splits) val
)
SELECT spend_date_id, active_window
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
JOIN numbering n
ON t.spend_date_id BETWEEN n.val AND n.val + 200 - 1
ORDER BY spend_date_id
```

result is

```
Row spend_date_id   active_window    
1   0               0    
2   350             1    
3   450             1    
4   500             1    
5   550             2    
6   650             2    
7   700             2
```

Obviously, above depends on number of rows in your table that drives size of array to process. To help address this - you can see that first I do `dirty split` where I just separate groups that are apart from each other for more than 200 thus have no chance to be in the same active window. So this potentially lower size of arrays for final `precise split`

Comment: Amazing. This works great, thanks! This confirms my train of thought too that this needed a loop to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this with scripting feature in BigQuery:

```
set delta = 199;
set t = array(select spend_date_id from dataset.table);
set buckets = '';
set n = array_length(t);
set i = 0;
set k = 0;
set startw = t[offset(k)];
set endw = t[offset(k)]+delta;

loop 
  if i >= n then leave;
  else
    set item = t[offset(i)];
    if item between startw and endw then 
      set grp = k+1;
      set buckets = if (
                        buckets = "", 
                        cast(grp as string), 
                        concat(buckets, ",", cast(grp as string))
                    );
    else
      set k = k+1;
      set startw = t[offset(i)];
      set endw = t[offset(i)] + delta;
      set grp = k;
      set buckets = if (
                        buckets = "", 
                        cast(grp as string), 
                        concat(buckets, ",", cast(grp as string))
                    );
    end if;
  set i = i+1;
  end if;
end loop;

select y as active_window from unnest(split(buckets, ",")) as y
```